# heroku cli login showing wrong account info

Tags: git, heroku, heroku-toolbelt

When I successfully log in on the command line using my personal account using:

```
$heroku login

Enter your Heroku credentials.
Email: ME@gmail.com
Password (typing will be hidden):
Authentication successful.
```

when I push with:

```
git push staging master
```

It gives me an error:

```
!  Your account SOMEONE-ELSE@gmail.com does not have access to MYAPP-staging.
!
!  SSH Key Fingerprint: FINGERPRINT_REMOVED
```

What's interesting is that the account shown in the error is someone that I added as a collaborator using the web interface. Heroku support isn't online until morning and I can't push out any code. I can reconfigure my environment etc but since the account in the error message was never used on my machine I feel like it might be an error on heroku's side.

Any ideas? Seen this before?

Thanks.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You need to manually add the ssh keys:

```
ssh-add -K ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

After that logout and login again

```
heroku logout

heroku login
```

Answer (score 4):

```
1. See all the accounts you are having:
heroku accounts

2. Add appropriate account to current repo:
heroku accounts:set <account_name>
```

Comment: You need to install the `accounts` plugin though: https://github.com/ddollar/heroku-accounts

Answer (score 0):

Try to regen your ssh key.

Take a look on this page : https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/keys

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps : *(Managing Your SSH Keys)*

**1. Creating and Adding SSH Keys locally**

> $ ssh-keygen -t rsa

```
Generating public/private rsa key pair.    
Enter file in which to save the key (/Users/adam/.ssh/id_rsa):
Enter passphrase (empty for no passphrase):
Enter same passphrase again:
Your identification has been saved in /Users/adam/.ssh/id_rsa.
Your public key has been saved in /Users/adam/.ssh/id_rsa.pub.
The key fingerprint is:
a6:88:0a:0b:74:90:c6:e9:d5:49:d6:e3:04:d5:6c:3e adam@workstation.local
```

**2. Adding this key to the Heroku account**

> $ heroku keys:add

```
Found existing public key: /Users/adam/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
Uploading SSH public key /Users/adam/.ssh/id_rsa.pub... done
```

**3. validating the connection**

> $ ssh -v git@heroku.com

*Now logout and login*

Also, use this **$ heroku keys** for checking keys

Reference: [Ckick here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/keys)